# Saving a literal file name as a variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filenames

My goal is to load some files listed in the table, extract the data, and save the results as a variable of the first file name. The lists in the table are user-input characters, which represent the names of the files that will be loaded soon. I'll give you an example because you may not understand what I mean. When A,B,C (strings) are listed in the table, my code will find where they are located(eg A.txt) and load their data. After the data has been collected from them, the results are saved in the name of the table like this : A(variable)= result_data(:4). Here is my code. please let me know the wrong place. *(Note that table is nx1 cell array using uitable.)*

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

data = get(handles.uitable,'data'); % get strings in table
for i = 1:size(data(:,1))  % count the #strings

fid = fopen([ data(i),'.csv' ]); %load the data and extract what I need
...
fclose(fid);
data(i) = result(row_1:row_2 , 4)  % this is the result_data 
% data(i) is variable string, so I am not sure whether to use the eval function.
```

end

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: compiler says " fopen([ data(i),'.csv' ]);" have a problem. It may not read  the data(i) as char. When I put the get (handles.edit1,'string') on file name, fopen worked well.

Comment: `data` is likely a cell array.  So you probably want `fopen([ data{i},'.csv' ]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your table to debug further here is my suggestions. `data` is probably a cell array since you are pulling it from a `uitable` as below.

```
data = get(handles.uitable,'data'); % get strings in table
```

So this line should error:

```
fid = fopen([ data(i),'.csv' ]);
```

Change it to this:

```
fid = fopen([ data{i},'.csv' ]);
```

or this:

```
fid = fopen([ char(data(i)),'.csv' ]);
```

When saving your results to the variable name  which matches your string I would suggesting using a structure with dynamic field names instead of a bare variable ... otherwise you will probably have to use eval which should be avoided.

So this (which isn't what you asked for):

```
data(i) = result(row_1:row_2 , 4)  % this is the result_data
```

Should become:

```
outData.(data{i}) = result(row_1:row_2 , 4)  % this is the result_data
```

If `data` is a cell array like you said containing {'A','B','C',...}
Then `outData` would be of the form below and contain each results.

```
outData.A
outData.B
outData.C
```

Comment: You mean just replace the end of the code for "outData.(data{i}) = result(row_1:row_2 , 4)" ? It says "The index exceeds the dimension of the matrix."

Comment: Which index exceeds which dimensions?  Your example isn't complete enough for us to tell exactly what you are doing.  Put a break point in your code and see if `data{i}` is erroring or  `result(row_1:row_2 , 4)` is causing the error.  Just copy and past those parts to the command line to see.  My answer is assuming `data` as extracted from the uitable is a cell array ... but without more information I have no idea what exactly you have going on in the code.

Comment: Seeing workspace, result is 22x6 double, data{i} is 6x1 cell. Though I only put 2 strings, data{i} represents 6×1 cell, not a 2x1 cell. data =

  6×1 cell 
    'a'
    'b'
    []
    []
    []
    [22×1 double]   It's so confusing since cells and matrixes are together. Do you have any other solution..?:(

Comment: I would need to see the uitable and what you have in there to help you any further.  sounds like there is more in the uitable than just the variable names. If data is 6x1 then your table has 6 rows with more than just the CSV names

Comment: If 'x' is a cell array of string and 'y' is a double then you can't do the plot as listed above.  You would need something like this first: ` x = str2double(x);` That will convert the cell array of strings to a double array.  Assuming the strings in the original `x` are all valid numbers.  If my post above answered your question then please upvote/accept it as the solution so this doesn't show as an unanswered question.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Iv'e  accepted your answer. Thank you.